# Print session array on other page PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

i need to print a session with a array in it on a other page but i am getting error message:

```
Undefined variable: _SESSION
```

Here is my code of the first page

```
<?php
//script opdracht1a.php
session_start();
// lees dit als: in de winkelwagen zitten 3 boeken en 1 pet
$_SESSION['winkelwagen'] = array( 'boek' => 3, 'pet' => 1 );

?>
```

Here is the code of the other page where i need to print the array of session 'winkelwagen'

```
<?php
//In de array aPrijzen zijn de prijzen opgeslagen van de producten
$aPrijzen = array ('boek' => 5, 'pet'=> 8 , 'jas' => 10, 'jurk' => 22); 
echo $_SESSION['winkelwagen'];
?>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have `session_start()` in your "other page".

Comment: And you can't `echo` out an array, either use `var_dump` or `foreach` loop to display array elements.